# Dark Souls - cannot log in on GFWL without entering product key that is already registered

Tags: steam, dark-souls, games-for-windows-live

I have installed Dark Souls from Steam, and try to play it online, but is asked to log in on GFWL. I have an account, on which Dark Souls is registered, but in order to log in, it keeps asking me to 'Enter the product key', and when I do it tells me that the product key is registered with another Live ID.

I do not have more than one Live ID (as far is I know), and when I log into my account through a browser, Dark Souls is on the list of games.

Any suggestion? Is it possible to see my key in the GFWL account?

Comment: I had to fight with GFWL a lot when playing their games. In particular, it produced something similar to what you're describing when I had any special symbols in my password. Seriously. I don't like GFWL since then. Also, quit the game and update the GFWL client manually.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you fixed it, but you can try this:

http://leviathyn.com/news/2013/01/08/fixing-games-for-windows-live-for-windows-8/

Ignore the fact that it was for Win8!

From the link:

1. Install Dark Souls (or any other Games For Windows Live title).
2. Try and start it. If it stays as a black screen and then crashes, that’s fine.
3. Uninstall Games For Windows Live — both the Marketplace client and
   the Redistributable. You can uninstall programs from your Control
   Panel.
4. Go to this link and install the old version of Games For Windows
   Live: [GFWL v3.3](http://www.filebowl.com/microsoft-games-for-windows-live-3-3.html)
5. After you start the old Games For Windows Live, you’ll be prompted to update the service by clicking on a link. Do so.
6. Install the new executable file as an Administrator (right click on
   the file and select **Run as administrator**).
7. The install will ask you to shut down any other running Games For
   Windows Live programs (it’s seeing the old client still running),
   select Ignore until the installation completes.The installer will close and so will the old version.
8. The installation this time will run longer and you’ll see the
   installer actually downloading and installing the newest version of
   GFWL.
9. Play Dark Souls (or whatever you’re trying to play)

.

Comment: Could you summarise the content of that link in case it's not around in the future? You can do this using the [edit] link